# XBox live in some countries

Tags: games, xbox-live

I am able to see XBox Live games in my (Croatian) marketplace and am able to try them but while installing I see that they are not in the games list but are installed. While I had the phone set up for the UK marketplace I had a XBox live page in the games menu but for Croatia this isn't there but I see the XBox live games...

Any idea when this will be sorted out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Croatia isn't on the list, sorry. There will not be an Xbox Live tile on phones running out of Croatia. http://www.xbox.com/en-US/live/countries .

If you want to supply feedback to Microsoft on this I've got a number of feedback routes for WP listed on this page - http://dfwiki.devfish.net/technology.Microsoft-feedback-routes.ashx .